# Simple error I think, but how can I require a gem installed file in one of my controllers? I get a LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, rubygems

I installed the venice gem, which can be found here. https://github.com/nomad/venice

After installing the gemfile, it suggests using

```
require 'venice'
```

I have done this in my `/api/v1/purchases_controller.rb` class. Like this...

```
require 'venice'

class Api::V1::PurchasesController < ApplicationController
```

However, I end up getting the following error

```
FATAL -- : 
LoadError (cannot load such file -- venice):
  app/controllers/api/v1/purchases_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Why is this. How can I use require this needed file in this one controller class (the only class I need it in).

Answer (score 1):

In Rails applications gems are usually handled with [Bundler](http://bundler.io/).

Add the following line to your applications' `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'venice'
```

Then run `bundle install` in your console and restart your application.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's because I didn't restart my application. I did the first two. I think I've gotten caught on this before. I'll try...